# invoking lambda with boto doesn't respect timeout

Tags: python, timeout, aws-lambda, boto, boto3

I'm invoking a lambda function with boto3, with:

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = client.invoke(
            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
            FunctionName=test_lambda_arn,
            LogType='Tail',
            Payload=json.dumps(data)
)
```

It's raising a `botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout` exception after 626 seconds. I have configured this lambda to time out after 100 seconds. I did so when I created it with boto. When I go into the AWS console it says that this lambda has a timeout of 1 minute and 40 seconds.

So why does the `invoke` command timeout after 626 seconds, and not after 100 seconds?

Is it because of retries? If so, how can I disable retries?

Edit: In the CloudWatch logs I can see multiple invocations for each `client.invoke` call. Therefore there is some automatic retry thing happening. Here are [the docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) for `client.invoke`.

Comment: Is the Lambda function actually being invoked? Do you see invocations happening in CloudWatch? It sounds like your code may be timing out trying to call the AWS API.

Comment: Yes I can see invocations in the logs. There are multiple log entries for a single `client.invoke`, so there is some retry thing happening.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a [botocore config](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html) object with a longer `read_timeout` value (and possibly other things), and pass it in when creating your lambda client:

```
import botocore
import boto3
            
cfg = botocore.config.Config(retries={'max_attempts': 0}, read_timeout=840, connect_timeout=600, region_name="us-east-1" )
           
client = boto3.client(
    'lambda', config=cfg, region_name="us-east-1",
     aws_access_key_id="*********", aws_secret_access_key="*********")

payload = {"input_array": input_arr}

result = client.invoke(
     FunctionName="**********", InvocationType='RequestResponse',
     LogType='Tail', Payload=json.dumps(payload,cls=NumpyArrayEncoder))
        

range = result['Payload'].read()
range_json = json.loads(range)
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted this issue on the boto3 git repo. They're going to add an option to `client.invoke` to disable automatic retries.

In the meantime, [here's a workaround](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1104#issuecomment-305136266).